# Legacy build environment in Docker container, incompatible with Jenkins agent

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a working Dockerfile that creates a build environment for a legacy app, and now I'd like to use that environment from Jenkins, ideally allowing for incremental builds.

The environment is too old to run a recent version of Java, which means it cannot be used as an agent directly.

Is there a way to run a series of build steps inside a container without the container itself running an agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the Jenkins docs, you could use your custom docker image as the [execution environment](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#execution-environment), assuming the server Jenkins is running on has Docker installed/running.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'your-custom-image' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'commands to run in your docker image here'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah nice, I can even do "agent { dockerfile true }" and get the Dockerfile from the repo. Only downside is that this plugin uses the commandline docker client instead of the API.